# MiniMagick shell_api is null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jruby, minimagick

I'm just getting started with MiniMagick within a Rails app and I'm having an issue that I can't seem to find referenced anywhere. My super-simple test case is as follows:

```
MiniMagick.configure do |config|
  config.cli = :graphicsmagick
end

image = MiniMagick::Image.open("Sunset.png")
image.resize "100x100"
image.format "png"
image.write('composite.png')
```

Which results in

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@project/gems/mini_magick-4.3.0/lib/mini_magick/shell.rb:32:in `execute'
```

The error is thrown by the `image.resize` call (although the same error is thrown by `image.valid?`, `image.blank?`, and undoubtedly others), and the line of code in the `MiniMagick::Shell` class throwing the error is:

```
send("execute_#{MiniMagick.shell_api.gsub("-", "_")}", *command)
```

Leading me to the conclusion that `MiniMagick.shell_api` is nil when it shouldn't be.

I'm on

- JRuby-1.7.18
- Rails 3.2.21
- Mac OSX 10.9.5
- GraphicsMagick 1.3.21 2015-02-28 Q8

I also saw the same error using ImageMagick 6.9.1-1 Q16 x86_64 2015-04-15. I can resize images without a problem using GraphicsMagick on the command line. I even wrote a simple Ruby class outside of my Rails app and the same code works fine within that!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I started digging through the MiniMagick code this morning to figure it out. Turns out `MiniMagick.shell_api` is a config item. The default value is "open3". I'm not sure why my Rails use case was overwriting the default with nil, however by adding the explicit configuration my problem is solved and goodness reigns.

```
MiniMagick.configure do |config|
  config.cli = :graphicsmagick
  config.shell_api = "open3"
end

image = MiniMagick::Image.open("Sunset.png")
image.resize "100x100"
image.format "png"
image.write('composite.png')
```